# My Android app is crashing on some device duo to java.lang.RuntimeException?

Tags: java, android, crash

My Android App is crashing on some devices due to java.lang.RuntimeException?
It crashes mostly on Android version 7.0 and 7.1. Some of the devices on which it has crashed is Redmi Note 4, Moto G (5) Plus, OnePlus 3. I don't know how why It is crashing but I am giving you the link of both the app and the source code here 
App Link : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.soloprogrammer.noughtsandcrosses

Source Code: https://github.com/iamshubhamsaurav/Noughts_and_Crosses

Comment: You've got to provide more information for anyone to be able to help you on this. Maybe the line of code it is crashing on? I would suggest at least trying to use an emulator for those devices and see if you can recreate the crashes. Genymotion might have images for those devices

Comment: Please provide logcat of the crash, maybe we don't have Redmi Note 4, Moto G (5) Plus, OnePlus 3 devices, but could see the problem from the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Your case, moving the (hi-res) all image from **drawable** to **drawable-xxhdpi** was the solution. I tested and It worked!
- You should resize image for folder **drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xxxhdpi**